# Grok pattern for quoted data separated by spaces

Tags: regex, logstash, grok

I have a log type as follows (single space delimiter):

"ABC" "DEF" "GHI" "JKL" "MNO" "PQR" "STU" "VWX"

Here is my code to match and sort this log type:

```
filter
{
   if [type] == 'logtype' {
     grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{QS:abc} %{QS:def} %{QS:ghi} %{QS:jkl} %{QS:mno} %{QS:pqr} %{QS:stu} %{QS:vwx}"}
      }
    }
 }
```

According to the online `Grok Debugger` this should work, however `Logstash/Kibana` shows the tag `"_grokparsefailure"` and does not sort any of the fields

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

02-beats-input.conf:

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
    ssl => true
    ssl_certificate => "/etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt
    ssl_key => "/etc/pki/tls/private/logstash-forwarder.key"
  }
 }
```

Comment: Weird, that grok works well for me, too. Do you mind pasting a real log line you're receiving?

Comment: I guess you should check for the condition if it works as you expected.

Comment: @Val When you say "log line" are you referring to the input to Kibana or a log from the Logstash logs?

Comment: `_grokparsefailure` happens when Logstash parses your log line in order to create a document from your log event. Kibana doesn't do such a thing, it simply shows you what's in the retrieved document, so the error must be happening on the Logstash layer.

Comment: @Val Gotcha. Is there a specific file I should look in to see what specifically is causing the _grokparsefailure? My "logstash.err, logstash.log, and logstash.stdout" all show logs that do not pertain to this issue

Comment: Can you show your input section?, i.e. the one that defines the `logtype` type

Comment: @Val I added the "02-beats-input.conf" file found in my /etc/logstash/conf.d. Is this what you're looking for? I am getting my logs from another machine via filebeat.

Comment: And `type: logtype` is defined in the Filebeat configuration I suppose? What I need to see is a line that Filebeat sends which you expect to get picked by that grok filter.

Comment: @Val I checked again to make sure and "document_type: logtype is defined in my filebeat config. I was able to extract the date/time using Grok earlier, however it just seems to be the quoted string that is giving me errors.

Comment: Show us such a string, otherwise we're just shooting in the dark here.

Comment: @Val My point being is that If I pass Logstash a date and use the date filter it is able to identify it. However, when passing a multitude of strings as shown above it will not be identified.

Comment: Your grok pattern might work on dummy data but in your real data there might be some details that you oversaw. I cannot help you if you don't show us some real data.

Comment: @Val To keep things very simple, the issue that I'm facing now is even when I pass Grok "xyz" and used the %{QS:xyz} filter, I get a grok parse error. However when using another filter. such as greedydata, the information is parsed just fine

Comment: Just for curiosity's sake, what about `%{QUOTEDSTRING:xyz}` which yes `QS` is short for, but since you mentioned that GREEDYDATA worked. . .

Comment: also, are there a variable number of quoted strings or spaces?